# cucumber step: how do i get the input data from a different step?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I have this scenario:

```
Given I am on the edit_stamp page
And I change the date to "14.5.2010"              #<-- i need this data
...
Then I should see that the new times has been set #<-- down here
```

I'm basically updating the date of a model, and in the last step I want to verify that the model was indeed updated with the date I selected in the first step.

How can I grab the selected date from the top, in the last step-definition?

```
Then(/^I should see that the new times has been set$/) do
  s = Stamp.first
  find_by_id("day_date#{s.id}").has_text?("14.5.2010")
end
```

This is what i have now, but I don't want to write the date(14.5.2010) into the step-definition, I want to fetch it from the previous step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
And (/^I change the date to "(.*?)"$/) do |input_date|
  @new_date = input_date
  # and here do whatever you are doing with the date
end

Then(/^I should see that the new times has been set$/) do
  s = Stamp.first
  s.date_or_whatever_attribute_you_are_using.to_s.should == @new_date
end
```

Those instance variables (@xx) persist alongside the whole Scenario.

Comment: By the way, using instance variables in your steps is considered bad practice. It makes it so steps are not dependent on the order in which they are run. More tid bits [here](http://www.slideshare.net/AtreyeeMaiti/keeping-your-cucumber-suite-maintainable-11140647).